# Searching a 365 Sharepoint List where I don't have access to site settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, search, crawling

We are a large organisation using Office 365 with our own tenant. I've created a List online by importing an Excel workbook. The problem is I can't get search working on the List.

I've added two columns to the list of indexed columns, and waited 24 hours. In Advanced Settings I have 'Automatic Index Management' on, and clicked the 'Reindex' button in there also.

A quick Google shows a lot of people mentioning site-level options and\or additional column properties that may need to be set, however I don't have access to these, and I won't.

Should the indexing work in this scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the list items are able to appear in search results.

[image]

Ask the site administrator to check it at web level:

[image]

If above settings are ok, check the crawl log at SharePoint admin center(with admin permission)to find whether the list has been crawled successfully.

Comment: It's set at List-level, we are a huge organisation and I would have to check who to ask at site level or above.